# Express and AngularJS - web page freezes when attempting to open home page

Tags: node.js, express, angularjs

I will explain the issue in as much detail as possible.

I am attempting to use AngularJS with Express and am running into trouble. I wish to display HTML files (not using a templating engine). These HTML files will have AngularJS directives.
However, I am not able to display a simple HTML file itself!

The directory structure is as follows:

```
Root  
---->public  
-------->js  
------------>app.js  
------------>controllers.js  
---->views  
-------->index.html  
-------->partials  
------------>test.html  
---->app.js
```

The contents of `public/js/app.js` is:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).
  config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/', {templateUrl: 'partials/test.html', controller: IndexCtrl});
$routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
}]);
```

The contents of `public/js/controllers/js` is:

```
function IndexCtrl() {  
}
```

The contents of the body tag in `views/index.html` is:

```
<div ng-view></div>
```

That's it. The expectation is that AngularJS will substitute the above view with test.html - `views/partials/test.html` whose contents are:

```
This is the test page!
```

enclosed within the paragraph tags. That's it!

Finally, the contents of `ROOT/app.js` file is:

```
var express = require('express');

var app = module.exports = express();  

// Configuration

app.configure(function(){  
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');  
    app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);  
    app.use(express.bodyParser());  
    app.use(express.methodOverride());  
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));  
    app.use(app.router);  
});

app.configure('development', function(){  
  app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));  
});  

app.configure('production', function(){  
  app.use(express.errorHandler());  
});  

// routes

app.get('/', function(request, response) {  
    response.render('index.html');  
});  

// Start server

app.listen(3000, function(){  
  console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", this.address().port, app.settings.env);  
});
```

**Now, when I do `$node app.js` in the root folder, the server starts without any error. However if I go to `localhost:3000` in the browser, the URL changes to `localhost:3000/#/` and the page gets stuck / freezes. I can't even check the console log in Chrome!**
This is the problem that I am facing. Any clue about what I am doing wrong?

Comment: what errors are thrown in browser console?

Comment: @charlietfl probably nothing. Mostly when the page seem to be freezing it's because the response isn't being ended.

Comment: `probably nothing`??  either errors are thrown or they aren't

Comment: @charlietfl None. The page simply freezes. Chrome then tells me after some time that the page is taking too long to respond and asks me if I want to kill the page.

Comment: @charlietfl Finally figured it out. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally figured it out - after many intense moments of hair pulling!!
The reason why the page freezes is because (explained step by step):

1. User launches localhost:3000
2. This requests the express server for '/'
3. Express renders index.html
4. AngularJS will render the template 'partials/test.html'.
5. Here, I am taking a wild guess - AngularJS has made a HTTP request for the page 'partials/test.html'.
6. However, you can see that express or rather app.js does not have a handler for this GET request. That is, the following code is missing:

   app.get('partials/:name', function(request, response) {
   var name = request.params.name;
   response.render('partials/' + name);
   });

inside `app.js` of the ROOT directory. Once I add this code, the page renders as expected.

Comment: Another (better) solution is to put your partials in your `public` folder so they will be served by the static middleware without needing to create specific route for them and without going through router/app stack. Note that your system is going to be very slow for users to load pages as they will need to download the index page from express, load the DOM and Angular, make an Http request call to get the partial, execute Javascript to render the page. Pretty complicated and slow IMO.

Comment: @jtblin I think your solution is applicable when your templates are public... In my cases, they are restricted and can be accessed only with proper authorizations...

Answer (score -1):

Try following the design pattern in [this working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/grendian/ajR3H/). Code shown below. You can replace the template option with templateUrl and it should still work fine.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/', {template: '<p>Index page</p>', controller: 'IndexCtrl'});
    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirect:'/'});
}]);

app.controller('IndexCtrl', function(){

});
```

Comment: I want to keep the `app.config()` inside app.js and the `app.controller()` inside controllers.js file. However, inside controllers.js, if I use local variable, it does not work. Do not know why